# Why does the scattering length it take the form it does?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

In partial-wave analysis, and particularly $s$-wave scattering, the scattering length can be defined as
\[\lim_{k\rightarrow 0} k\cot(\delta_0)=-\frac{1}{a_0}.\]
My question is why is it defined this way? i.e. what is the physical importance of the quantity $k\cot(\delta_0)$ that it should be used in this expression?

Comment: hint: what is $a_0$ for a hard sphere of radius $R$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It will be $R$. It still seems a bit ad hoc though - that just because it gives you $R$ for a sphere that it is a useful quantity for other potentials.

Answer (score 0):

A brief section on S-wave scattering is found here - http://www.int.washington.edu/users/mjs5/Class_560/lec560_2/node2.html
it discusses the physical significance of the cot term. 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
I’ll summarize and try not to plagiarize at the same time. The cot term, as I’m sure you know, just comes from the mathematics. Many years ago others  also questioned the presence of the cot term. They went on to show mathematically that using a power series expansion, it represents correctly the limits of the scattering amplitude. Also, it can be used to calculate the bound states as well.

Comment: Hi john, thanks for your answer. Although your link does explain the answer to this question nicely - link only answers are kind of discouraged (see [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/861/70392)) so if you could explain what the links says that would be great. :)